# How to alter specific rows of 2d list based on value of boolean dependent on the list

Tags: java, arrays, list, multidimensional-array, arraylist

How can I incorporate this boolean T/F check into this code without it going through the entire arraylist>?

the situation is as follows;

```
arraylist<arraylist<Integer>> bigArray....elig arraylist<Boolean>
elig.size() == bigArray.get(0).size();
bigArray is rectangular (i.e. no differing sizes of interior Lists
```

my code is as follows:

```
for(int j=0; j<(bigArr.size()); j++) {  //lets assume this is ==10           
  for(int e=0; e<(ballotArr.get(0).size()); e++) {   //assume == 5
    if(elig.get(e) == false) {          
        for(int k=0; k<(ballotArr.get(0).size()); k++) {  //==5
            bigArr.get(j).set(k, big.get(j).get(k)-1);
        }
    }
  } 
}
```

As can be clearly seen, this will loop thru the most interior for loop 10 times anytime elig.get(e)==false, and subtract from all of the indices.

what is necessary is for elig.get(e) to hold a steady value while the for(int k) processes, and then afterwards get the next value (at least I believe this is the solution)

the goal is to subtract 1 from all the rows who have a value of 1 in a specific column.

Thanks for any help/suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Using the library implementations, this can be sped up slightly.  The use of customized collections *may* make this faster yet, but that's out-of-scope here.  You **are** up against certain iteration constraints, so there's only so much you can do in any case.

It will be helpful to break up the procedure into smaller methods:

```
public static void decrementColumns(List<List<Integer>> rows, List<Boolean> mask) {
    final List<Integer> maskIndicies = getMaskIndicies(mask);
    // We're locked into this iteration because we have to modify every row.
    for (List<Integer> row : rows) {
        apply(maskIndicies, row);
    }
}

// Your big savings will come from figuring out the indicies.
// This allows us to make the iterations-per-row smaller - 
//   assuming not every row (or even most) is set to 'true'!
public static List<Integer> getMaskIndicies(List<Boolean> mask) {
    final List<Integer> maskIndicies = new ArrayList<Integer>(mask.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < mask.size(); i++) {
        if (mask.get(i)) {
            maskIndicies.add(i);
        }
    } 
}

public static void apply(List<Integer> maskIndicies, List<Integer> row) {
    // We're locked into this iteration, needing to apply the transformation
    // to every column included.
    for (Integer index : maskIndicies) {
        final Integer modified = row.get(index) - 1;
        row.set(index, modified);
    }
}
```

Please note that this is **NOT** threadsafe, so be careful.  I also didn't write in any safety checks, so...

---

**EDIT:**

Upon re-reading the question, I've realized I initially mis-read what the code was doing (and I'm kicking myself - somehow I dropped a loop).

The revised version:

```
public static void decrementColumns(List<List<Integer>> rows, List<Boolean> mask) {
    final int count = getMaskCount(mask);
    // We're locked into this iteration because we have to modify every row.
    for (List<Integer> row : rows) {
        apply(row, count);
    }
}

public static void int getMaskCount(List<Boolean> mask) {
    int count = 0;
    for(Boolean flag : mask) {
        if (!flag) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

public static void apply(List<Integer> row, int count) {
    for (int index = 0; index < row.size(); index++) {
        final Integer modified = row.get(index) - count;
        row.set(index, modified);
    }
}
```

Please note that this *still* isn't doing ~exactly~ what your original code does, only what I'm assuming you're attempting to do, given your 'requirements' text.  For one thing, you define at least **2** additional list, that you don't give the relationships for - one of which I'm fairly sure is a typo.  If you edit your question for clarity, I may be able to provide a better answer; there's a few ambiguous or contradictory things going on between your code and your question text.  Please note that while your original code runs in `O(m * (n ^ 2))`, the minimum (and my version) runs in `O(n + (m * n))`.

Comment: Any suggestions on doing this my way (i.e. not sped up slightly)? I really want to get the logic down on this.